# Append file name with source folder using the FIND command

Tags: shell, file, directory

I need to strip files out of a number of directories that all have the same file name a.txt. The difference comes from the parent folder so

example1\a.txt
example2\a.txt
...

so I am hoping to run a FIND command that will capture a.txt but not overwrite the file as it moves from folder to folder.
so the output would be

example1_a.txt
example2_a.txt

So from another post the FIND command I want is the following

```
find . -name "a.txt" -execdir echo cp -v {} /path/to/dest/ \;
```

So I want to modify in some way to append the source folder to the file. so my guess is to manipulate {} somehow to do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one liner might be possible, but you could use this:

```
#!/bin/bash

targetprefix="targetdir"
find . -name "a.txt" -print0 | while read -r -d '' line
do
    path=$(dirname "$line")
    newpath=$(echo "${path#./}" | tr '/' '_')
    target="$targetprefix/$newpath"
    
    filename=$(basename "$line")
    
    cp -v $line $target/$filename
done
```

- change variable "targetprefix" to be the destination directory you desire.
- this `find` with `-print0` and `while` comes from https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001
- since results from `find` all start with "./", I use `"${path#./}"` to remove that prefix.
- the `tr` replaces all subsequent "/" with an underscore.  This will take care of sub directories
- WARNING: I did not test all "weird" directory and filename formats for proper execution (like carriage returns in filenames!).

Comment: Thanks for this, I needed to make a slight tweak but otherwise perfect. Too bad this is too much for Find though

Comment: It could be done within the `--exec` of a `find`, using a series of `$( commands )` and splitting them with `;`, but that line would be super long, hard to debug and understand.  As I stated, some guru might have a one liner for this...  Or do an awk script within the `--exec`...?  Simpler just to create that script and call it IMHO.